# Pandas: create a period based on date column

Tags: pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe

```
ID              datetime 
11              01-09-2021 10:00:00
11              01-09-2021 10:15:15
11              01-09-2021 15:00:00
12              01-09-2021 15:10:00
11              01-09-2021 18:00:00
```

I need to add period based just on datetime if it increases to 2 hours

```
ID              datetime                 period
11              01-09-2021 10:00:00        1
11              01-09-2021 10:15:15        1
11              01-09-2021 15:00:00        2
12              01-09-2021 15:10:00        2
11              01-09-2021 18:00:00        3
```

And the same thing but based on ID and datetime

```
ID              datetime                 period
11              01-09-2021 10:00:00        1
11              01-09-2021 10:15:15        1
11              01-09-2021 15:00:00        2
12              01-09-2021 15:10:00        1
11              01-09-2021 18:00:00        3
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get difference by [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html), convert to hours [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html), comapre for `2` and add cumulative sum:

```
df['period'] = df['datetime'].diff().dt.total_seconds().div(3600).gt(2).cumsum().add(1)
print (df)
   ID            datetime  period
0  11 2021-01-09 10:00:00       1
1  11 2021-01-09 10:15:15       1
2  11 2021-01-09 15:00:00       2
3  12 2021-01-09 15:10:00       2
4  11 2021-01-09 18:00:00       3
```

Similar idea per groups:

```
f = lambda x: x.diff().dt.total_seconds().div(3600).gt(2).cumsum().add(1)
df['period'] = df.groupby('ID')['datetime'].transform(f)
print (df)
   ID            datetime  period
0  11 2021-01-09 10:00:00       1
1  11 2021-01-09 10:15:15       1
2  11 2021-01-09 15:00:00       2
3  12 2021-01-09 15:10:00       1
4  11 2021-01-09 18:00:00       3
```

Comment: But it checks just difference between neighbour strings. I meant to add a new period after 2 hours. For example from 2021-01-09 10:00:00 to 2021-01-09 12:00:00 - period 1, 2021-01-09 12:00:00 to 2021-01-09 14:00:00 - period 2 etc